# Application.OnKey triggered by two keys

Tags: vba, excel

I want to develop a kind of stenotype typing keyboard, but for that to work I'd need that a macro is triggered only when two, three or four keys are pressed simultaneously, just as it works with Shift, Alt, Ctrl, i.e:

```
Application.OnKey "+^%{RIGHT}", "macro"
```

Is there any simple way to achieve that? Because I'd need to program a few hundreds of combinations for it to work properly.

Comment: This is not possible with `.OnKey`. Also Excel is not meant for coding a keyboard it is meant for calculating. Therefore you chose the wrong tool. But you might have a look at [AutoHotkey](https://autohotkey.com/).

Comment: Maybe use the event "keydown"?